# Prevent nested elements from triggering an event for parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Structure:

`.parent (has if/else to toggle on click) -> .child (has nothing)`

```
<div class="parent">Parent
    <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

The parent element is styled to hide overflowing content and toggle its height on click. When the user clicks, the parent element will expand to show the child element. I want users to be able to click on the child element without the parent element toggling back to its original size and hiding the child element. I want the toggle to only happen on the parent.

I realize the child element is still contained within the parent element's clickable area, but is there a way to exclude it?

Comment: stop the propagation !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Solution 1: Compare target with currentTarget:**

```
$("#parentEle").click( function(e) {
    if(e.target == e.currentTarget) {
        alert('parent ele clicked');
    } else {
        //you could exclude this else block to have it do nothing within this listener
        alert('child ele clicked');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ggQ3/1/)

`e.target` will be the element that started the event.
`e.currentTarget` will be where it currently is (bubbling up) which will be `parentEle` in this click event as that's what this is listening for.

If they are the same, you know the click was directly on the parent.

---

**Solution 2: Stop the propagation before the event hits the parentEle:**

The other option is to prevent the event from bubbling up in the first place if there is a click on a child element. That can be done like this:

```
$("#parentEle").click( function(e) {
    alert('parent ele clicked');
});
$("#parentEle").children().click( function(e) {
    //this prevent the event from bubbling to any event higher than the direct children
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ggQ3/3/)

---

The main difference between the two is that the first solution will just ignore the event in this listener and allow it to keep bubbling up. This may be necessary if you have a parent of this `parentEle` that needs to get the event.

The second solution stops any  click events from bubbling past `parentEle`'s direct children. So if there was a click event on a parent of `parentEle`, they would never see these events either.

Comment: +1 but perfomance wise, I suggest you change `.find('*')` to `.children()`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon True enough as I suppose we don't need to care about bubbling below that.

Comment: Works great. Went with stop propagation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `event.stopPropagation();`:

```
$('#a').add('#b').click(fun1);

function handler(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // now do your stuff        
}
```