# Click listener fired when click on child input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I labeled this answer as angularjs because I'm using angular, but maybe it's a generic javascript problem.

I have a table, which rows can be selected by clicking on each row. Each cell of each row contains interactive elements such as links, buttons and input fields. The problem is that, when I click on any element contained on the row, the click event bubbles and reaches the row click listener, and then the row gets selected.

My current workaround is to check the element name that is triggering the event, and if it is not the row, ignore it.

```
  var target = e.target || e.currentTarget;
  if (/button|input|^a$|select/i.test(target.nodeName) || /glyphicon/i.test(target.className)) {
        // Only reacth if the click does not comes from a button or an input
        console.log(e)
        return
      }
```

The way I'm installing the event listener is with `ng-click="switchSelected($index,$event)"`

There should be a better way.I don't know if it is possible to restrict it to the clicked element, but I don't want that neither, because if they click on an empty space, I want the row to be selected.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409551/prevent-nested-elements-from-triggering-an-event-for-parent-element

Comment: For what you're trying to do, I think you may have already found the right approach. You may be able to refine it, but it's probably going to be a process of filtering the event target.